# Why is my function not working properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sudoku

I am working on a sudoku puzzle and I have everything working properly except that it doesn't generate valid numbers. My function is supposed to generate valid numbers, though. (my fiddle() function I got from [here](http://blog.forret.com/2006/08/a-sudoku-challenge-generator/).

Here is my generatePuzzle() function:

```
// Generate sudoku puzzle
function generatePuzzle() {
    for(var h = 1; h <= 10; h++) {
        fiddle(rowVal);
    }
    //emptyCells();
    putCellVal();
    for(var f = 0; f < 80; f++) {
        if (document.forms[0].elements[f].value != '') {
            document.forms[0].elements[f].readOnly = 'readonly';
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, it doesn't generate valid numbers. My `fiddle()` function is still wrong (http://blog.forret.com/2006/08/a-sudoku-challenge-generator/).

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/oliverni/rq5m6/) for my JSFiddle.

If you are not a sudoku player, here are the rules:
[image: Sudoku Grid]
Each row must have every number from 1 - 9 **only once**
Each column must have every number from 1 - 9 **only once**
Each 3 x 3 square with a thicker border must have every number from 1 - 9 **only once**

**JSFiddle link:** http://jsfiddle.net/oliverni/rq5m6/

Comment: And `valid numbers` are?

Comment: I just want to know which numbers would be valid. How do we know what are valid numbers and invalid numbers? Please don't expect everyone here to be a Sudoku player to be able to know already what to fix.

Comment: As they said....we need more information but is this a problem - `fiddle(rowVal);` should be `fiddle(h);` since no variable "rowVal" is called. Unless that was left out.

Comment: @SpencerMay The variable `rowVal` is defined early in the program. Click on the jsfiddle link to see it!

Comment: Still reviewing but off the top so far - those massive arrays should actually be objects with nested arrays inside assigned to properties.  But that's just semantics really lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in the fiddle function to swap, rows / columns / blocks are correct, and you can actually inspect the rowVal matrix, which stores correct value.

The problem lies on the way you assign the value to the input elements.

```
function putCellVal() {
    var z = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < rowVal.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < rowVal[i].length; j++) {
            document.forms[0].elements[z].value = rowVal[i][j];
            z++;
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently you use a table for each block, and from the assignment logic above, you are actually assigning a "row" of rowVal to a "block". You can check the value of rowVal[0], which is [1,9,8,4,2,3,6,5,7], the value in your first block

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="x0y0" maxlength="1">
    <td><input type="text" name="x1y0" maxlength="1">
    <td><input type="text" name="x2y0" maxlength="1">
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="x0y1" maxlength="1">
    <td><input type="text" name="x1y1" maxlength="1">
    <td><input type="text" name="x2y1" maxlength="1">
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="x0y2" maxlength="1">
    <td><input type="text" name="x1y2" maxlength="1">
    <td><input type="text" name="x2y2" maxlength="1">
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! T was stupid and didn't change that part when I changed the table formatting. I used to have it as one giant table, but I changed it so that the user could see the squares.

Comment: Actually, my fiddle function is wrong because it is still generating invalid numbers. Here I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it! I changed the one giant table to 9 small tables, but now instead of x0y5 being element 5, it is now element 11!